# Scrapy is not downloading the tags from the responses

Tags: python, request, response, scrapy

I am presently working on scrapy, below is my spider.py code

```
class ExampleSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = {"careers-preftherapy.icims.com"}


    start_urls = [
        "https://careers-preftherapy.icims.com/jobs/search"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        pageCount = hxs.select('//td[@class = "iCIMS_JobsTablePaging"]/table/tr/td[2]/text()').extract()[0].rstrip().lstrip()[-2:].strip()
        for i in range(1,int(pageCount)+1):
            yield Request("https://careers-preftherapy.icims.com/jobs/search?pr=%d"%i, callback=self.parsePage)

    def parsePage(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        urls_list_odd_id = hxs.select('//table[@class="iCIMS_JobsTable"]/tr/td[@class="iCIMS_JobsTableOdd iCIMS_JobsTableField_1"]/a/@href').extract()
        print urls_list_odd_id,">>>>>>>odddddd>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
        urls_list_even_id = hxs.select('//table[@class="iCIMS_JobsTable"]/tr/td[@class="iCIMS_JobsTableEven iCIMS_JobsTableField_1"]/a/@href').extract()
        print urls_list_odd_id,">>>>>>>Evennnn>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
        urls_list = []
        urls_list.extend(urls_list_odd_id)
        urls_list.extend(urls_list_even_id)
        for i in urls_list:
            yield Request(i.encode('utf-8'), callback=self.parseJob)


    def parseJob(self, response):
        pass
```

Here after opening the page i am achieving pagination like

```
https://careers-preftherapy.icims.com/jobs/search?pr=1
 https://careers-preftherapy.icims.com/jobs/search?pr=2
```

...........so on

I yielded request for each url(suppose here there are 6 pages).When scrapy reached 1st url
i am trying to collect all href tags from the first url
`(https://careers-preftherapy.icims.com/jobs/search?pr=1)` 
and when it reaches second url same collecting all href tags.

Now in my code as u see there are totally 20 href tags in each page in that 10 href tags are under `td[@class="iCIMS_JobsTableOdd iCIMS_JobsTableField_1"]`  \
and remaining are under `td[@class="iCIMS_JobsTableEven iCIMS_JobsTableField_1"]` .

What the problem is here scrapy some times downloading the tags and some times not i dont know whats happening, i mean when we run spider file two times it is downloading and when another time its returning an empty list like below

**1st time run:**

```
2012-07-17 17:05:20+0530 [Preferredtherapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://careers-preftherapy.icims.com/jobs/search?pr=2> (referer: https://careers-preftherapy.icims.com/jobs/search)
[] >>>>>>>odddddd>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
[] >>>>>>>Evennnn>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

**Second time run**

```
2012-07-17 17:05:20+0530 [Preferredtherapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://careers-preftherapy.icims.com/jobs/search?pr=2> (referer: https://careers-preftherapy.icims.com/jobs/search)
[u'https://careers-preftherapy.icims.com/jobs/1836/job', u'https://careers-preftherapy.icims.com/jobs/1813/job', u'https://careers-preftherapy.icims.com/jobs/1763/job']>>>>>>>odddddd>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
[preftherapy.icims.com/jobs/1811/job', u'https://careers-preftherapy.icims.com/jobs/1787/job']>>>>>>>Evennnn>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

My question is why it is sometimes downloading and sometimes not, please try to reply me its really helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What the problem is here scrapy some times downloading the tags and
>   some times not i dont know whats happening

To understand what is happening you should debug. My guess is that your xpath query returns an empty list, because you got an unexpected page.

Do something like:

```
def parsePage(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    urls_list_odd_id = hxs.select('//table[@class="iCIMS_JobsTable"]/tr/td[@class="iCIMS_JobsTableOdd iCIMS_JobsTableField_1"]/a/@href').extract()
    print urls_list_odd_id,">>>>>>>odddddd>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
    urls_list_even_id = hxs.select('//table[@class="iCIMS_JobsTable"]/tr/td[@class="iCIMS_JobsTableEven iCIMS_JobsTableField_1"]/a/@href').extract()
    print urls_list_odd_id,">>>>>>>Evennnn>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"

    if not urls_list_odd_id or not urls_list_odd_id:
        from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
        inspect_response(response)

    urls_list = []
    urls_list.extend(urls_list_odd_id)
    urls_list.extend(urls_list_even_id)
    for i in urls_list:
        yield Request(i.encode('utf-8'), callback=self.parseJob)
```

When you'll get to the shell type `view(response)` to view the downloaded page in browser (for example in Firefox) and you will be able to test your xpath queries and find out why they return nothing.
[Here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#invoking-the-shell-from-spiders-to-inspect-responses) is more info about scrapy shell.

Comment: Thank very very much for replying, actually i am getting xpath result when i checked that individually with scrapy shell "url" , suppose if i got xpath result for page1 and page2 for first run, i am not getting same result with same xpath when i run second time, but individually working fine .....

Comment: That's why i suggested you not to run `scrapy shell` but invoke the shell when you get no results - it will open the offending page

Answer (score 0):

You can use `open_in_browser()` to open the response in the browser:

```
def parsePage(self, response):
    from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
    open_in_browser(response)
```